# convert to arbitrary number of inputs while being case insensitive

Tags: python

So I am given a menu and the food rating, i have to create a data structure, then make a getInfo function, and findCheapest function.

getInfo(item) takes 1 item and prints outs its price and ratings.
findCheapest(item1, item2) takes in 2 items, checks if items are in menu and gives the cheapest. I have written this far here is where i am struggling.

how to make all the input case insensitive for both functions, but still return correctly formatted words. Eg:

getInfo("tEa") should return:
Tea- price: 7. Rating: 4

I get you could do string compare and convert it to lowercase but you can't do that in a set cause then it will print wrong and how do you do it and still compare each value properly.

The second part i am struggling at is for the findCheapest function how make it so that it can take an arbitrary number of values and still print the cheapest without changing the data structure too much.

So i implemented a formatText(item) function that converts to the correct format.

Here is the code:

```
menu= {"Tea", "Coffee", "Cookie", "Chips"}

price={

    "Tea": 7,
    "Coffee": 5,
    "Cookie": 2,
    "Chips": 3
}

rating= {
    "Tea": 4,
    "Coffee": 4.5,
    "Cookie":5,
    "Chips": 2
}

def getInfo(item):
    if item in menu:
        print item + "- price: %s." % price[item] + " Ratings %s" %rating[item]
    else:   
        print "This item was not found: " + item

def findCheapest (item1,item2):
    if item1 in menue and item2 in menue:
        if (price[item1] < price[item2]):
            print item2+ " is the cheapest"
        elif (price[item1] > price[item2]):
            print item1 +" is the cheapest" 
    else:
        print "An item was not found." 

getInfo("tEa")
getInfo("coFfeE")
findCheapest("tEa", "coFfeE")
```

Comment: Figured out the case sensitive part any ideas for the arbitrary number of inputs???

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the user input, use capitalize function. and get the price and rating. Capitalize returns with just the first letter of each word in capital, all others lower

```
list_of_items = [x.capitalize() for x in raw_input.split()]
find_cheapest(list_of_items)

def find_cheapest(list_of_items):
    cheapest_price = 12345
    cheapest_item = ""
    for item in list_of_items:
        # Get the price of the item and check with the least price
        item_price = price.get(item,None)
        if item_price and item_price < cheapest_price:
            cheapest_price = item_price
            cheapest_item = item
    if cheapest_item:
        return cheapest_item + "is the cheapest"
    else:
        return "No Items were found"
```

Comment: but if keys are lower case in menu [] which is where search happens then you print them lower case as well. no?

Comment: @user3064626 You can use capitalize function then. Edited my answer

Comment: but that will capitalize everything, i don't want it to print in lower case of uppercase, if tEa should print as Tea, Coffe etc like it is in the menu items. or could it be I'm not getting your answers at all?

Comment: @user3064626  The capitalize function does not capitalize everything. it does exactly what you are asking for. `"tEa".capitalize()` returns `Tea` and not `TEA`

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas for the arbitrary number of inputs part?

Comment: @user3064626: My answer already contains that. Convert the given strings as list of strings by using the split() function as I have shown in the code

Comment: @user3064626 by this code, you can enter `Tea Coffee Cookie sOMething` as the input and pass the list as argument to find_cheapest, where you can check the cheapest item

Answer (score 0):

Use either @Aswin Murugesh solution to make everything uppercase or lowercase
Or
wrt your current setup, you can use `capitalize()`
Or
construct following string (1st char upper using `upper()`+rest char lower using `lower()`) to make the 1st char capital.

```
getInfo("tEa".capitalize())
getInfo("coFfeE".capitalize())
findCheapest("tEa".capitalize(), "coFfeE".capitalize())
```

Apply it to the input values or as the 1st step in your method

Answer (score 0):

```
    my_menu= ["Tea", "Coffee", "Cookie", "Chips"]

    price={

        "Tea": 7,
        "Coffee": 5,
        "Cookie": 2,
        "Chips": 3
    }

    rating= {
        "Tea": 4,
        "Coffee": 4.5,
        "Cookie":5,
        "Chips": 2
    }

    def isItemInMenue(item="", menu=[]):
        for x in menu:
            if x.lower() == item.lower():
                return x
        return ""

    def getInfo(item):
        item_ = isItemInMenue(item, my_menu)
        if item_:
            print item_ + " - price: %s." % price[item_], "Ratings %s" % rating[item_]
        else:   
            print "This item was not found: " + item_

    def findCheapest (item1, item2):
        item1_ = isItemInMenue(item1, my_menu)
        item2_ = isItemInMenue(item2, my_menu)
        if item1_ and item2_:
            if (price[item1_]  price[item2_]):
                print item1_ + " is the cheapest" 
        else:
            print "An item was not found." 

    getInfo("tEa")
    getInfo("coFfeE")
    findCheapest("tEa", "coFfeE")
```

Answer (score -1):

Code looks pretty good so far.  One easy fix is to use the `upper` and `lower` functions to properly format your items before doing the logic.

```
def format_item(someItem):
     return " ".join(x[0].upper() + x[1:].lower() for x in someItem.split())  

print format_item("tEA") #Tea
```

Then you can just call format item before the rest of your logic.  For example.

```
def findCheapest (item1,item2):
    item1 = format_item(item1)
    item2 = format_item(item2)
    ...
```

Comment: how would you account for other menu items like Chicken Sandwich or Club Turkey Sandwich

Comment: I didn't realize that multiword (whitespace separated) menu options were a problem.  I'll fix it